# Show that $\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7})}$ is a UFD

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, unique-factorization-domains, euclidean-domain

It is known that the ring of integer is a Dedekind domain which means that it is a UFD iff it is a PID. Since $-7\equiv1$ mod $4$, we have that $\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7})}=\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{-7}}{2}\right]$. Now I read something in the sense of: if $\alpha:=\frac{1+\sqrt{-7}}{2}$ has an irreducible minimal polynomial mod $2$ and mod $3$, then we have a PID; I don't know anything about that. I think I have stated that wrong since the minimal polynomial is $f_{\alpha}=x^2-x+2$ which is reducible mod $2$.

Dr. Math:
We pick an arbitrary complex number $x + iy\in\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$, and we must find a 
suitable lattice point:

$$z = r + s\alpha = (r+s/2) + i(s\sqrt{7})/2.$$

It is natural to try to have the real and imaginary parts of
$(x + yi - z)$ as small as possible.

Let's start with the imaginary part $ y - s\sqrt{7}/2$.  We take $s$ as 
the closest integer to $2y/\sqrt{7}$.  This will give us the following:
\begin{align*}
  | 2y/\sqrt{7} - s | &\leqslant 1/2\\
  | y - s\sqrt{7}/2 | &\leqslant \sqrt{7}/4.
\end{align*}
Now, we turn to the real part $x - r - s/2$.  If we select $r$ as the 
integer closest to $(x - s/2)$, we will have:
\begin{align*}
  | x - r - s/2 | \leqslant 1/2.
\end{align*}
Putting both relations together, we get:
$$
  N(x + yi - z) = (x - r - s/2)^2 + (y - s\sqrt{7}/2)^2
                \leqslant 1/4 + 7/16
                < 1$$

as desired. Hence, Euclidean domain, so PID, so UFD.

Is this proof correct and can it be applied in all cases of showing that $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2}\right]$, $\square\neq d\in\mathbb{N}$ is a Euclidean domain?

Comment: It's a Euclidean domain.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes, but how can I show that? Is there a method for showing such?

Comment: I didn't find the exact place yet but the conclusion that all $\mathbb Z[ 1+\sqrt d / 2]$ for $d \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ are euclidean is false. Something like this should work for $7$ i think, but there should be some part that breaks down once $d$ is large.

Comment: @AlexJBest: You're right and an example for what you say is $ d = -19 $.

Comment: The Minkowski bound for $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-7})$ is ~1.68..., if you have this machinery available to you.